# In angular how to check user password and email on login time using laravel api

Tags: angular

I am making angular login and register app using laravel api . how to check user email and password are valid or wrong.

**login.component.html**

```
    <div style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
                  <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-top: 60px">     
                        <h2>Login</h2>
                        <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" formControlName="email" class="input" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.email.errors }" placeholder="Email"/>
                                <div *ngIf="submitted && f.email.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                                    <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="input" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.password.errors }" placeholder="Password" />
                                <div *ngIf="submitted && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                                    <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>

                                <a routerLink="/register" class="btn btn-link">Register</a>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

login.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
        import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

        import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
        import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
        import { AuthenticationServiceService } from '../_services';
        import {AlertService} from '../_services';

        @Component({
          selector: 'app-login',
          templateUrl: './login.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
        })
        export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
          loginForm: FormGroup;
          loading = false;
          submitted = false;
          returnUrl: string;
          constructor(
            private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
            private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private router: Router,
            private authenticationService: AuthenticationServiceService,
            private alertService: AlertService
          )     { 

            if (this.authenticationService.currentUserValue) { 
              this.router.navigate(['/']);
             }
          }

          ngOnInit() {
            this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
              email: ['', Validators.required],
              password: ['', Validators.required]
          });

          // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
          this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
          }
          get f() { return this.loginForm.controls; }
           onSubmit() {
                this.submitted = true;

                // stop here if form is invalid
                if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
                    return;
                }

               //this.loading = true;
                this.authenticationService.login(this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value)
                    .pipe(first())
                    .subscribe(
                        data => {
                            this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                            console.log(data);
                        },
                        error => {
                            this.alertService.error(error);
                            this.loading = false;
                    });
            }

        }
```

authentication-service.service.ts

In this service i am calling api and want to check email and password of user on login time please help me how to check .

```
     import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import {User} from '../_models/user';


    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })

    export class AuthenticationServiceService {
      private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
      public currentUser: Observable<User>;
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
            this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
       }
       public get currentUserValue(): User {
       return this.currentUserSubject.value;
       }

       login(email: string, password: string) {

             return this.http.post<any>(`http://localhost:8000/api/login`, { email, password })
            .pipe(map(user => {

                return user;
            }));
    }

    logout() {

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your form is valid or not on submission of the form instead of in your service as follows

```
       onSubmit() { 
           // if form valid then call authentication API 
            if (this.loginForm.valid) {
            this.submitted = true;
               //this.loading = true;
            this.authenticationService.login(this.f.email.value, 
             this.f.password.value)
                .pipe(first())
                .subscribe(
                    data => {
                        this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error => {
                        this.alertService.error(error);
                        this.loading = false;
                   });
              }  
         }
         else {
            // stop here if form is invalid
         }
```

Comment: you can skip else part because using above code you can't able to call authentication service till your email password is valid

Comment: i am removed else part...@sneha pawar

Comment: how to stop users to redirect when password is worng @Sneha Pawar

Comment: @dineshkr. we already stopped if your form is invalid and you redirect those users who fill proper data in your service so what you want to do more?

Comment: using above code you will get result same as you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186760/discussion-between-dinesh-kr-and-sneha-pawar).